# После установки docker desktop не запускается windows

Tags: docker

После установки docker desktop не запускается windows, что делать?

после установки docker desktop нажимаю на close and restart - происходит перезагрузка но windows не загружается (черный экран). пробовал устанавливать разные версии docker desktop, во всех случаях все было также

Comment: Исправили как-то? Можно удалить его?

Comment: Система лежит, что поделать с ней не знаю, переустанавливать нельзя. Что делать, нашли ли решение?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема та же, смог только вернуть систему. Зайдите через безопасный
F8 + shift вроде выберите безопасный режим и винда подниметься, удалив последние обновления докера, это проблемы с установкой виртуальных систем... как установить не знаю, сам сюда пришел искать ответ

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос